# Variable issues regarding placement in code

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I'm really not sure what the appropriate title to this is but I'll try to explain what I am out after here in the description and do my best with the title. Its also monday morning so bear with me!

Currently I am working with EntityFramework, trying to insert data into a local database. However, when I try tell it where to go (which I am obviously doing wrong), it complains about a variable/namespace, and quite frankly I'm not sure if this is simply outside my knowledge range or if its the monday tiredness kicking in.

**Current code:**

```
var db = new Bootstrap.Database1Entities(); 

db.CalendarDatas.Add(new db.CalendarData
                {

                    Day = 1-1-2015,
                    Text = "Test"


                });



               db.SaveChanges();
```

**Current error code:**  CS0246: The type or namespace name 'db' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

*However, between these two command "blocks" I also have a command block selecting everything from the database with the same names and namespaces, which works, if thats relevent at all. Keep in mind I am very much a newbie at this this far.*

```
var dag = new DateTime(year, month, i);
                var calenderInfos = (from c in db.CalendarDatas
                                     where c.Day == dag
                                     select c).ToList();
```

That is the command block selecting everything from the database, and as a newbie to C# I would imagine that, since CalendarDatas works here, it should also work on the insert command block? Probably wrong but thats as far as I can say atleast.

Comment: Are you sure you have the type `db.CalendarData`? I guess it's rather `Bootstrap.CalendarData`, assuming from the type name of your db context.

Comment: @WiktorZychla "db" does select Bootstrap.Database1Entities though, I'll test what you're saying though, just to be on the safe side. EDIT: Tried, and getting a different error code which makes it seem unlikely that Bootstrap.CalendarData is the case ( CS0234: The type or namespace name 'CalendarDatas' does not exist in the namespace 'Bootstrap' (are you missing an assembly reference?) )

Comment: Which line is the error occurring on?

Comment: @KarlGjertsen On here it would be on the third, doesn't seem to completely like the "db.CalendarDatas.." line.

Comment: @Xariez: what is `CalendarDatas`? I bet the type name is `Bootstrap.CalendarData` not `CalendarDatas`.

Comment: Can you show the definition for the CalendarDatas property?

Comment: Which version of Entity Framework are you using?

Comment: I'll edit the original post to make a thing more clear in regards to that, one moment!

Comment: @WiktorZychla: But the error message says db.

Comment: @KarlGjertsen: he doesn't have the namespace `db`, this is what the error says. `db` is a name of a variable.

Comment: @JasonEvans Not entirely sure,actually. If I click on it in the reference list, it tells me "Version 6.0.0", but not sure if thats what we're out after.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
db.CalendarDatas.Add(new CalendarData
            {

                Day = new DateTime( 2015, 1, 1 ),
                Text = "Test"


            });
```

The 'new db.CalendarData...' will cause the compiler to search for a namespace called 'db'

Comment: Tried it and seems like it doesn't recognize (the type/namespace) "CalendarData"

Comment: @Xariez then you probably forgot to add the proper namespace to your file, or misspelled the name of the class

Comment: You'll have to tell it where you defined CalendarData then. But i am certain this is your error.
'new db.CalendarData' does not make sense.

Comment: CalendarData is the table in the database though, so to me it doesn't surprise me much it doesn't find it?

Comment: @Xariez: the problem is you are a newbie and you don't really even understand what people talk about. Sure, CalendarData is the table but also, the `CalendarDatas` property of your db context must have some type. People correctly assume the type name is `CalendarData`, the very same name your table has. For some reason however, the type name is different or you have it in a different namespace. Thus, people tell you to go to the definition of the `CalendarDatas` property and just check its type. Could you do this, perhaps?

Comment: I am, indeed a newbie and I won't deny that whatsoever, I can though admit I'm not sure what/how you want me to do. The one and only thing that pops up into my head is to right click and hit Go to definition on it, and that gives me: "  public virtual DbSet<CalendarData> CalendarDatas { get; set; }  "

Comment: Here's something you could try.
    `var db = new Bootstrap.Database1Entities(); 
    var newItem = db.CalendarDatas.Create();
    newItem.Day = "1-1-2015";
    newItem.Text = "Test";
    db.CalendarDatas.Add(newItem);
    db.SaveChanges();`

Comment: Look then now, your type name **is** `CalendarData`. It possibly just resides in a different namespace. Could you right click the `CalendarData` in `DbSet<CalendarData` and select "go to definition" from the context menu and then check the type definition and the namespace it is defined in?

Comment: @JakobOlsen Completely changed the error code, its now "CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.DateTime'"

Comment: That's probably because i don't know the type of ´newItem.Day´. If it is a DateTime, then you need to do 'newItem.Day = DateTime.Parse("1-1-2015");

Comment: @JakobOlsen: it is safer to have `new DateTime( 2015, 1, 1)` than parsing a particular string. The latter will fail in any environment with different localisation settings.

Comment: @WiktorZychla You know, fun fact. I just tried to go back to the Calendardatas definition to do what you asked for, but getting "Cannot navigate to defniition" from Visual Studio. This just got even more interesting.

Comment: @Xariez: three options: either you have the class but the definition is wrong and it doesn't compile (so the compiler can't navigate to it), either you don't have the definition at all or, the last option, it exists in another project you haven't referenced. Could you search manually through your project for the defintion of the `CalendarData` class?

Comment: @WiktorZychla I could, but its funny that it worked earlier and not now. Besides, the solution Jakob Olsen had seemed to work, so I think I might as well go with that? I appreciate your help a lot though!

Comment: @JakobOlsen That does seem like its working, actually. Atleast its inserting things to the database. If you want to post is as a answer, go ahead!

Answer (score 1):

db.CalendarData is a property that cannot be created. You need to create a new instance of a class, not the property.

Can you replace db with the correct namespace in the line below:

```
new db.CalendarData
```

I would recommend changing your code to use the using statement. I'd also simplify the code until you find out what is causing the error.

```
using(var db = new Bootstrap.Database1Entities())
{
    var item = new CalendarData
                   {
                       Day = new DateTime( 2015, 1, 1 ),
                       Text = "Test"
                   };
    db.CalendarDatas.Add(item);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: `new db.CalendarData` will fail, just as it does in the original code.

Comment: This is wrong. How can the compiler resolve `new` on `db.xxx` if `db` is a name of a variable? To `new` something in C# you need a type name. I think you need to edit the answer or delete it, as most probably it will be downvoted.

Comment: @WiktorZychla the important advice here is "simplify the code". Given the comments, I suspect the code has many more issues, missing namespaces etc but the OP only posted a snippet

Comment: Could very well be. I tried usign the code and while it first complained on the fact that there were now two "db" definitions, I cleaned that up to, but surprisingly that lead back to the original error message, comlpaining on the "db" part of it.
EDIT: Tried removing the db from where you wanted, lead to it not recognizing CalendarData.

Comment: Is there a namespace missing from CalendarData?
Bootstrap.CalendarData perhaps?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: advices are given in comments. Answers should really try to answer a particular issue. Thus, the first approach to this answer, from before the edit, was clearly not a good answer. This one is much better.

Comment: Thanks @WiktorZychla. I'm new to contributing here and I'm still learning! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Problem fixed! 
I truly appreciate everyones help, but the solution that Jakob Olsen came with seemed to do the trick this far. Originally posted in the comments.

```
var db = new Bootstrap.Database1Entities();
var newItem = db.CalendarDatas.Create();
newItem.Day = "1-1-2015";
newItem.Text = "Test";
db.CalendarDatas.Add(newItem);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Glad you got it working. I would look at using the Using keyword, which helps manage resources. A good place to learn more would be here: http://www.dotnetperls.com/using

Comment: @Xariez: looking how much people helped you, you definitely should pick one of answers, Jakob's or Karl's, and mark as correct. Picking your own answer as correct means no one gets any credit from helping you.

Comment: @WiktorZychla Alright, you do make a point there. None of the actual "answers" are the answer though, unless someone can fix that for me. The current solution only exists in the comments as far as I can see. I'll pick the one closest to it thugh and upvote the cmoments to make it more visible. Good job for pointing it out!